# Передать в Gmail Api кастомные параметры

Tags: javascript, gmail

Как реализовать функцию, которая будет принимать в аргументе Email, subject, text, и передавать их в сообщение, которое отправляется через GMail Api? На javascript единственный способ вызвать методы google api, насколько я понял, это

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
```

Но здесь нельзя передать нужные мне параметры в onload функцию. Есть ли еще какой-то способ вызвать объекты и методы Google Api?

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понимаю причем тут передача параметров в `handleClientLoad`, но можете попробовать следующий код:

```
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"
  onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad(<ВАШИ ПАРАМЕТРЫ>)"
  onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
</script
```

Замените `<ВАШИ ПАРАМЕТРЫ>` на Ваши параметры через запятую.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, это выглядит тем, что мне нужно. Но таким способом у меня почему-то не определены методы апи, такие как gapi.client.setApiKey и т.д.

Comment: Вы вызывали `gapi.client.setApiKey` в handleClientLoad? Даже не знаю, вроде функция должна выполнится после загрузки скрипта.